# Concatenate two matrices multiple times in a specific way

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, concatenation

> Suppose we have two square matrices "x" and "y" of dimension nxn and a numeric variable "a". I want to concatenate those matrices a number of times depending on the parameter "a", so to obtain a bigger square matrix "xy". 
>   This new matrix will contain only copies of the first two matrices arranged in the following way : matrix "x" on the main diagonal of the new matrix "xy" and matrix "y" in all other entries of the matrix "xy".

Here some example to clarify the question:

input: two 2x2 matrices

```
x=np.array([[1,1],[1,1]])
y=np.array([[2,2],[2,2]])
```

for `a=2`
expected output:

```
xy=np.array([[1,1,2,2],
            [1,1,2,2],
            [2,2,1,1],
            [2,2,1,1]])
```

for `a=3`expected output:

```
xy=np.array([[1,1,2,2,2,2],
            [1,1,2,2,2,2],
            [2,2,1,1,2,2],
            [2,2,1,1,2,2],
            [2,2,2,2,1,1],
            [2,2,2,2,1,1]])`
```

what I'm looking for is a code for the generic case with `a=n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way of doing that may be.

Given `x`, `y` and concatenation factor `a`, first create a [block diagonal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.block_diag.html) matrix `X` of `a` blocks of `x`, then take all [non zero](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) index `X_idx` of it, *i.e.* the index of block diagonal elements. Here, I suppose that your `x` does not contain zero components.

Now, create a matrix `Y`, which is just a [tile](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) of shape `(a,a)` of `y` blocks. Finally, let's make the diagonal blocks of `Y` zero by applying the `X_idx` mask to it and sum `X` and `Y` to obtain the desired `XY` matrix. It follows:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import block_diag

x = np.array([[1,1],[1,1]])
y = np.array([[2,2],[2,2]])    
a = 3

X =  block_diag(*[x]*a)
X_idx = np.nonzero(X)
Y = np.tile(y,(a,a))
Y[X_idx] = 0
XY = X + Y
```

which outputs the corresponding `XY`

```
>>> array([[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
           [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
           [2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2],
           [2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2],
           [2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1],
           [2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1]])
```

In case `x` have zero values, just replace `np.nonzero` call by:

```
X_idx = (np.repeat(np.arange(a*x.shape[0]),x.shape[0]),
         np.r_[[np.tile(np.arange(i,i+x.shape[0]),x.shape[0]) for i in range(0,a*x.shape[0],x.shape[0])]].ravel())
```